# Using dtype object in read_csv throws an UnboundLocalError

Tags: pandas, object, dtype

I wanted to preserve leading zeros in original data, so I used the following code:

`actual18 = pd.read_csv("S:/2018/ACTUAL18.txt", dtype={'district': object})`

It worked fine. But then I wrote a function that used the exact same code and when imported as a module, I got the following error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'object' referenced before assignment

I wrote *str* instead of *object* and it worked, but I do not understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhere later your code have you defined `object`? Otherwise this should work.

Comment: Why would I need to define it, is it not one of the Pandas dtypes?